# Assignment to Heap Allocated Memory

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was writing a singly-linked list in C and cannot understand this following code.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
  int val;
  struct ListNode* next;
} ListNode;

int main() {
  /*Say I allocate this list to say 1->2->3->4->NULL*/
  ListNode* node = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
  ListNode* n1 = node; // An ordinary pointer
  ListNode* n_heap = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // A heap allocated pointer
  n_heap = node->next; // 2->3->4->NULL
  n1->next = NULL;
}
```

Now from the above example, I had assumed that `n_heap` to be `NULL` as well. But even after `n1->next = NULL;`, `n_heap` is still `2->3->4->NULL`. So is the `node->next` copied to `n_heap`? or is it that `n_heap` now points to the original heap located `node->next`, and the `n1->next` now set to `NULL`? Does this mean `node` wasn't initially the owner of `node->next` data?

Comment: The memory you allocate from the heap is not necessarily aligned like you may think. It's whatever available memory the kernel decides to allocate to you after calling `malloc`. Also, you aren't explicitly setting a value to any of your ListNodes, so if you are seeing 2->3->4->NULL that sounds like undefined behavior. It may just so happen that `malloc` returned adjacent memory addresses in your case, but again that isn't something you can rely on.

Comment: You first allocate a ListNode and assign the pointer to `node`. The content of this node, including its `next` member is undefined. You then make a copy of the `node` pointer in `n1` - just the pointer, the node is not copied. You then allocate a second ListNode, assigning its pointer o `n_heap`. You then overwrite that pointer's value with the (still undefined) value of `node->next`. Finally you set that value inside `n1->next` (a.k.a. `node->next`) to `NULL`.

Comment: By the way, this code doesn't appear to appropriately initialize a linked list, so if you are having difficulty understanding what's happening, this isn't a great example to learn from since it isn't really doing anything notably of value.

Comment: @h0r53: Re “… necessarily aligned like you may think. It's whatever available memory the kernel decides to allocate…”: `malloc` returns memory suitably aligned for any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement (i.e., suitable alignment for any of the basic C object types), per C 2018 7.22.3 1. `malloc` is a standard C library routine, not a kernel routine. It is typically implemented by using kernel services to allocate pages of memory, which are provided at page-aligned addresses, which `malloc` then chops up as needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, but I was simply saying a single `malloc` followed by another `malloc` doesn't guarantee the returned memory addresses are adjacent to one another. It isn't 100% clear, but the OP seems to be operating under the assumption that this is the case.

Comment: The line `n_heap = node->next;` throws away (leaks) the memory allocated on the previous line, overwriting it with garbage (since `node->next` has not been assigned a value in the code shown).  There are no values shown.  There is no way that anything gets close to a list `1->2->3->4->NULL`.  If modified appropriately, you could get `1->2->NULL` with the allocations shown.  You've made your code too minimal — you need to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> int main() {
>   /*Say I allocate this list to say 1->2->3->4->NULL*/
>   ListNode* node = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
> ```

`node` is a pointer to dynamically allocated data.  On a C implementation with a stack / heap distinction, that will be on the heap.

> ```
>   ListNode* n1 = node; // An ordinary pointer
> ```

`n1` now points to the same dynamically-allocated data that `node` does.  It is no more or less "ordinary" than `node` is.

> ```
>   ListNode* n_heap = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // A heap allocated pointer
> ```

(On success) `n_heap` points to different dynamically allocated data.  The pointer itself has the same scope and storage duration as `node` and `n1`, and is exactly as "ordinary" as they are.

> ```
>   n_heap = node->next; // 2->3->4->NULL
> ```

Now the memory to which `n_heap` previously pointed is leaked, because no pointers to it remain.  `n_heap` points to the same memory that `node->next` does.  Which is the same memory that `n1->next` does.

> ```
>   n1->next = NULL;
> ```

Now the value of the *pointer* object accessible as `n1->next` (and also as `node->next`) is set to NULL.  This has no effect on *the data* to which that pointer object previously pointed, nor on variable `n_heap`, which still points to the data in question.

> ```
> }
> ```
>
> Now from the above example, I had assumed that `n_heap` to be `NULL` as
> well. But even after `n1->next = NULL;`, `n_heap` is still `2->3->4->NULL`.

You are failing to distinguish between pointer objects and the objects to which their values point.  Assigning `NULL` to `n1->next` sets the value of one pointer object.  It does nothing to the object to which the old pointer value pointed.  It does nothing to other, distinct pointers to the same object.  And on the other hand, `n_heap` *is not* `2->3->4->NULL`,  It is a pointer distinct from all those nodes, *whose value* points to the node containing `2`.

> So is the node->next copied to n_heap?

Yes, that's what an assignment does, but not in the sense I think you mean.  Again, assigning `n_heap = node->next` copies the pointer value stored in `node->next` to `n_heap`.  Those two distinct pointer objects then both contain values pointing to the same data.

> or is it that `n_heap` now points
> to the original heap located `node->next`, and the `n1->next` now set to
> `NULL`?

Yes and no.  Again, neither the object designated by `n_heap` nor the one designated by `node->next` contain the data you are describing as `2->3->4->NULL`.  Instead, they both contain the *address* of the node containing the first of those values.

> Does this mean `node` wasn't initially the owner of `node->next`
> data?

It depends on what you mean by "owner".  Certainly neither `node` nor `*node` is a *container* of the data to which `node->next` points.  As the term "owner" is usually applied to pointers, it is about responsibility for freeing the pointed to data, not about storage layout.  Responsibility to free is a question of data and control flow in the program, not a property of the data itself.